# Gradle 2.2.1 Cobertura 2.2.4 and SonarRunner 2.4 Code Coverage is 0%

Tags: gradle, sonarqube, cobertura, sonar-runner

I am facing the issue with code coverage being set to 0% in SonarQube.
It is a gradle/groovy project. Gradle version is 2.2.1;JDK is 1.7.0_51-b13

Using sonar-runner(2.4) to publish the results in SonarQube.

I can see the coverage.xml being generated. However the file has hits="0" and condition-coverage="0% for every line number element.

The class(XX.groovy) in src/main/groovy in SonarQube shows as below:
        Lines:  113
        Lines of code:  76
        Functions:  4
        Complexity: 12
        Complexity /function:   3.0
        Comments (%):   19.1%
        Comment lines:  18
        Classes:    1
However the Coverage section shows as below:
        0.0%    by unit tests   Line coverage:  0.0% (0/34)     Branch coverage:
        0.0% (0/34)
Any reason why the coverage is set to 0%/? 
In terms of cobertura properties, I have got below set:

```
    project(':Stub') {

       apply plugin: 'cobertura'
       cobertura {
         coverageFormats = ['html', 'xml']              
         coverageIgnoreTrivial = true                   
         coverageIgnores = ['org.slf4j.Logger.*']           
         coverageReportDir = file("$buildDir/reports/cobertura")    
         coverageSourceDirs << project.sourceSets.main.groovy.srcDirs

      }

   }
```

More info:

I am running gradle clean build test, followed by gradle cobertura. When I run gradle cobertura, below is the outcome:
        :Stub:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
        :Stub:compileGroovy UP-TO-DATE
        :Stub:processResources UP-TO-DATE
        :Stub:classes UP-TO-DATE
        :Stub:instrument
        Cobertura 2.0.3 - GNU GPL License (NO WARRANTY) - See COPYRIGHT file
        :Stub:copyCoberturaDatafile
        :Stub:generateModuleManifest
        :Stub:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
        :Stub:compileTestGroovy UP-TO-DATE
        :Stub:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
        :Stub:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
        :Stub:test
        :Stub:generateCoberturaReport
        Cobertura 2.0.3 - GNU GPL License (NO WARRANTY) - See COPYRIGHT file
        Report time: 120ms
        Cobertura 2.0.3 - GNU GPL License (NO WARRANTY) - See COPYRIGHT file
        Report time: 308ms
        :Stub:performCoverageCheck SKIPPED
        :Stub:coberturaReport UP-TO-DATE
        :Stub:cobertura

The performCoverageCheck is always skipped.

Comment: You should double-check the configuration of Cobertura in the Gradle build. As long as coverage is 0% in the generated report, SonarQube can't do anything.

Comment: I created an issue in https://github.com/stevesaliman/gradle-cobertura-plugin/issues/79, as I am using the cobertura plugin.